# Smaller mp4 file duration time

Tags: opencv

I'm creating an mp4 file at 60 FPS from a measurement which gives me frames at a variable FPS. I've  done this by adding the same frame until the timestamp it give's me a new frame. Even the frame count * FPS should give me a specific duration time the final file has a smaller duration time. For example from  a duration time of 8 minutes the final file has only 5 minutes. I use opencv 3.4.3 with H264 codec. Why is this happens?

This is the function:

```
   void ExporterChannel::ProcessMFCImage(Timestamp _timestamp, const std::string& _filename, const std::string& _data)
{
  static bool first = true;
  static long long accumulated_time_error = 0;
  static long long first_timestamp;

  static structs::SensorNearData::MFC::CameraImage mfc_image_struct;
  static pb::SensorNearData::MFC::CameraImage  mfc_image_pb;

  if (first)
  {
    first = false;
    mfc_image_pb.ParseFromString(_data);
    pb2structs::convert(mfc_image_pb, mfc_image_struct);
    first_timestamp = _timestamp;
    Size frameSize(mfc_image_struct.image_width, mfc_image_struct.image_height);
    bool color_mode_rgb = (config_.color == "true");
    if (color_mode_rgb == true)
    {
      video_file.open(_filename, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'), FPS, frameSize, true);
    }
    else
    {
      video_file.open(_filename, CV_FOURCC('H', '2', '6', '4'), FPS, frameSize, false);
    }
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!video_file.isOpened())
    {
      ExporterException("Could not open the output video file for write\n");
      return;
    }
    HandleMFCImage(mfc_image_struct);
  }
  else
  {
    if ((long long)_timestamp < (first_timestamp + STEP))
    {
      accumulated_time_error += first_timestamp + STEP - (long long)_timestamp;
    }
    else
    {
      while ((long long)_timestamp >= (first_timestamp + 2 * STEP))
      {
        HandleMFCImage(mfc_image_struct);
        first_timestamp += STEP;
      }
      accumulated_time_error += (long long)_timestamp - (first_timestamp + STEP);
      if (accumulated_time_error >= STEP)
      {
        HandleMFCImage(mfc_image_struct);
        accumulated_time_error -= STEP;
      }
    }
    mfc_image_pb.ParseFromString(_data);
    pb2structs::convert(mfc_image_pb, mfc_image_struct);
    first_timestamp = (long long)_timestamp;
    HandleMFCImage(mfc_image_struct);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share code or pseudo code on how you detect frame drops and add duplicated frames? Probably there is a bug in it.

Comment: Hi Micka. I've added the code. tks. HandleMFCImage just adds the frame to the  video.

Comment: could you change it to something like `double currentFps = (currentTimestamp - firstTimestamp)/numberOfRecordedFrames; while(currentFps  < FPS) addImage;`? Or at least just compute the totalRecordedFPS in this way and check whether this explains the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.